# Too many false matches between images using OpenCV SIFT and DescriptorMatcher

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to match two sets of images and trying to detect occurrences of one set within another using OpenCV SIFT for keypoint and feature detection followed by OpenCV DescriptorMatcher (Bruteforce/Flann) and KNN match for calculating the actual matches.

Code reference from OpenCV documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html

Although this works fine most of the time, there are a few instances where a high number of false matches are detected. All such instances appear to have a similar pattern 
[image: see screenshot]

I want to understand the reason behind such false matches and also how this can be prevented.
I have tried blurring the images as a pre-processing step.
This helps bring down the false matches but also brings down the true matches in other images.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Code snippet below:

```py
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
    kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("BruteForce")
    matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)
    good_points = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.65 *n.distance:
            good_points.append(m)
    result = cv2.drawMatches(original, kp_1, image_to_compare, kp_2, good_points, None)
```

Comment: Could you paste actual images? There's only white and black background. How do you expect feature descriptor to work on that?

Comment: I am unable to paste the actual image due to copyright issues. I have replaced the left and right images with black and white respectively for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Could you at least run it against some test images?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my query, this code works fine for many combinations of images. However in some images I get this kind of result. Basically what is happening is that multiple keypoints in left image are mapping to the same keypoint in the right image.